# NodeJs Mongoose: Unable to receive recipes data outside of forEach loop even though it appears to show while iterating inside the loop

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am querying Category data via mongoose, grabbing an array of meal_ids, looping through each Id and finding it in another collection called Recipes where I am grabbing some more data. In each iteration I am pushing it to an array. In the end im attempting to send that array of objects as JSON. However all I am getting is blank output. While iterating when I console log the data, everything appears correctly.
I also console logged that same array twice, once in forEach and once outside and noticed that, the one outside is being executed first which isnt making sense to me. Is it because findById is an async call? And if thats the case how could I then control that flow so that the outside array has the data.
Below is my entire code for the endpoint:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Category = require('../models/category');
const Recipe = require('../models/recipe');

/**
 Endpoint: /category/:id
 Outcome: List of recipes belonging to category
 */

 router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

    Category.findById(req.params.id, 'mealIds', (err, category) => {
        const recipesReceived = [];
        if(!err) {
            if(category) {

                category.mealIds.forEach(mealId => {
                    Recipe.findById(mealId, 'name category cuisine image' , (err, recipe) => {
                        recipesReceived.push(recipe);
                        console.log(recipesReceived); //shows data
                    });
                });
                console.log(recipesReceived); //shows blank. somehow ends up executing before the console log within forEach condition
            }
        else {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
  });
 });
 module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  category.mealIds.forEach(async (mealId) => {
                let recipe=await  Recipe.findById(mealId, 'name category cuisine image')
                if(recipe)recipesReceived.push(recipe);

            });
            console.log(recipesReceived);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @A.Abdelhak. But the result is still same i.e blank output. Also im finding it difficult to understand your code. You removed callback from findById and then checking for that recipe which in my code would get populated as a result of the  callback. Could you please clarify the flow.

Comment: I now kind of understand that you using await till recipe has the value but it doesn't solve the original problem because even though recipesReceived within forEach does have the value but it doesnt pass down to the console log outside of forEach. If you use console log within forEach you will notice the data is there but outside of it its not there. Also console log outside of forEach gets executed first due to async call to findById. Basically we need a way to defer the execution of the outside console log till recipesReceived has the entire array populated